# Not able to get the object in IE10

Tags: javascript

document.getElementById returns null in ie10.The below code works fine in ie8.How can I fix this issue.
Note:If I pass complete string it works in ie10.String append is failing

```
morphPricingDetailsForInstrument = function(DOAlias,isManualFlag) {
    alert(DOAlias);
    var periodTypeId = document.getElementById("currencyDO."+DOAlias+".fBperiodTypeId");
}
```

Comment: So you have an ID that contains periods written in weirDoCasE ?

Comment: What DOAlias contains? Can you provide a demo on jsfiddle?

Comment: DOAlias is holding a string i.e..,pricingDetailDOsLeg1.

Comment: Is working fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/wcdngyvw/, can be a casing issue? Can you provide a demo?